# How to set rewrite rule for same filename and directory name?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have upgrade my Wamp server 2.0 to 2.4.

I had set rewrite url to hide extension.

But after sever upgraded the rewrite rule is not working for same directory name and file name.
Here is the structure,

```
root-

   test/ (Directory)

   test.php (File)
```

Rewrite rule is as below I have used

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

The above code was working fine in version 2.0. But after upgrade to 2.4 it is not working
for same name file and dirctory.
When I used **/test/** it goes to **test dir**, but before this it was gone to **test.php** file

I have tried different combination but not worked.

Thanks.

Comment: Is any rewrite rule working for you on new setup? Can you show your full .htaccess?

Comment: To clarify, do you want `/test` and `/test/` to both go to `/test.php`? Or should one of them go into the directory?

Comment: thanks for reply, yes I want both to go `test.php`

Comment: here is the code that used in .htaccess, `Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /not-found.php`

Comment: Yes Anubhava, rewrite rule is working, but for same file name and directory name it is not working.